# THE ranking: citation score

Tags: citations, ranking

The Times Higher Education [university ranking](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats) seems to be a popular metric to rate universities (although rankings are kind of weird). I wanted to understand how they actually create the scores and read a bit about it. However, I couldn't find any detailed information about the citation component in their scoring system (which accounts for a whopping 30% of the total), and I'm wondering if anyone has information about how it is generated.

---

Here is their [methodology section](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/world-university-rankings-2021-methodology), but I don't think it really states how various trends of citations across many subjects are comprehensively reviewed, and especially how those numbers are transferred into a scoring system of a 100 total. There is an [additional document](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/breaking_news_files/the_2021_world_university_rankings_methodology_24082020final.pdf) at the end of that link with more information, but the citation score methodology is still a little shrouded in mystery. Let me quote them:

> We examine research influence by capturing the average number of times a university’s published work is cited by scholars globally. This year, our bibliometric data supplier Elsevier examined more than 86 million citations to 13.6 million journal articles, article reviews, conference proceedings, books and book chapters published over five years. The data include more than 24,000 academic journals indexed by Elsevier’s Scopus database and all indexed publications between 2015 and 2019. Citations to these publications made in the six years from 2015 to 2020 are also collected.

But...how exactly? Taking a raw average of citations per publication would be possible, but across how many years and what are the normalization factors for the subjects? They are again vague about this:

> The data are normalised to reflect variations in citation volume between different subject areas. This means that institutions with high levels of research activity in subjects with traditionally high citation counts do not gain an unfair advantage. We have blended equal measures of a country-adjusted and non-country-adjusted raw measure of citations scores.